# Exercise 3.8 of Ross' Elementary Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing

Let $a,b \in  \mathbb{R}$. Show if $a \leq b_1$ for every $b_1 > b$, then $a \leq b$.

It took my a while to realise that there is no mistake in this formulation. And then someone helped me with the strategy.

Proof by contradiction:

Let $a>b$ and let $b_1 = \frac{a+b}{2}$. But how do I derive a clean contradiction from this?

I multiply with 2:

$2(b_1) = b_1 +b_1 = a+b$.

Now I can see some contradiction. Since $b_1 >b$, it has to be the case that $a > b_1$ for the equation to work out, which contradicts our assumption. But how do I write that down in formalese?

Secondly, I have a hard time seeing how the false assumption that $a>b$ is what leads to the contradiction. $b_1 +b_1 = a+b$ would have been false anyway for $a =b_1$ at best and $b_1 >b$.

I feel really stupid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by Aditya, I write down an easy to understand proof.

Assume $a>b$.

$a>b \iff a+b>b+b \iff a+b>2b \iff \frac{a+b}{2}>b$. Now we let $b_1=\frac{a+b}{2}$ and take the assumption that $a \leq b_1$. It follows that $\frac{a+b}{2} \geq a \iff a+b \geq2a \iff a+b \geq a+a \iff b\geq a$. And that last inequality is in contradiction to our assumption from which we wanted to derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 5):

As we have $a>b$, then by this assumption we have $\dfrac{a+b}{2} > b$, so the choice of $b_1$ is dependent on the assumption of $a>b$. Now if we put
$ b_1 \ge a $, we immediately  get $b \ge a$, which is a contradiction

Comment: "immediately" seems to be the wrong choice.

Comment: @Maximillian just because you don't understand it doesn't mean Aditya's proof was wrong. Please read it more carefully to understand the clean proof, or ask questions for points of clarification.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I did not say that his proof was wrong. In fact, his answer was upvoted by me and it helped me to write my own more beginner-friendly answer. I just object to the use of "immediately" as some manipulations have to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach:

Assume 
$\displaystyle a > b \implies (a - b) > 0$ 
and establish a contradiction.

Let $t = (a - b)$ and  $b_1 = a - \dfrac{t}{2}.$

This yields a contradiction because:

- $t > 0 \implies \dfrac{t}{2} > 0.$
- $b = a - t \implies b_1 = b + \dfrac{t}{2} \implies b_1 > b. $
- $a - b_1 = \dfrac{t}{2} > 0 \implies a > b_1.$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof will not hold, because you made two assumptions, so a contradiction will yield two possible false assumptions. The proof is not trivial:

By request, $\{a;b\}\in\mathbb{R}$, $a\leq b_1$ whenever $b_1>b$. This means that we are left only with two possible intervals $\{A\ni a;B\ni b\}\subset\mathbb{R}$:
$$A=(-\infty;b_1]$$
$$B=(-\infty;b_1)$$
and the propositions in the exercise are equivalent to:
$$a\in A\Leftrightarrow b\in B$$
This fact together with $b_1>b$ proves $a=b_1\Leftrightarrow b<a$  and that $a\text{ and }b$ are in $A\cap B$.
Going back to the order relations, we have that $a<b_1$ and $b<b_1$, so the only thing we can surely state about $a$ and $b$ is that they share a least upper bound $b_1$. If you make the claim: $a>b$, then there exists an $a$ wich is an upper bound for all $b$‘s, but $a<b_1$, so $a$ is a lower bound than $b_1$, wich is a contradiction, so it must be the case that $a\leq b$ (Trivially true, because it can’t be greater than), hence your proof is over.
However, if you make another assumption (like the $b_1=\dfrac{a+b}{2}$) you’ll have to prove first that the assumption you made is true before you can discard the first one, but that is impossible, since the only way you can prove $b_1=\dfrac{a+b}{2}$ is by showing that $a$ and $b$ both equal $b_1$, but $a+b<2b_1$, hence $a=b≠b_1$. This shows that the two assumptions would cause the proof to fail.

Comment: Thanks, but at this stage of the book, the notion of "upper bound" has not been introduced.

Comment: I’ts a supposition i made that many of the tools i used are not introduced at that stage of the book. I just thought that it was necessary to clarify $\textit{why}$ $a\leq b$ Is a true statement: it’s not the case that $a$ can actually BE less than $b$. It just happens that it can’t be greater. :)

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment

‘ Secondly, I have a hard time seeing how the false assumption that $a>b$ is what leads to the contradiction.’ Intuitively speaking, you can imagine the real line, with $x>y$ if $y$ is on the right side of $x$. Then, if $a>b$, there is definitely a point $c$ between $a$ and $b$. Namely $c$ is at the right side of $b$, but left side of $a$, which contradicts what is stated: points ‘righter’ than $b$ is ‘non-righter’ than $a$. But this intuition is quite informal, and you should construct a $c$ to make it rigorous. In your post you have constructed $c=\dfrac{a+b}{2}$. There are definitely other constructions, for instance $\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b$ for any $0<\lambda<1$.